# clojure destructuring vs haskell-like argument pattern matching

Tags: haskell, clojure, functional-programming

Coming from Haskell I find it hard in Clojure to traverse some data types.
In Haskell if I like to do some recursion on a type, in most basic case something like

```
foo (x : [])     = Just value
foo (x : y : xs) = bar y (foo xs)
foo _            = Nothing
```

is just fine.

But I think Clojure's destructuring is nothing near of being powerful as Haskell's pattern matching. Is there a nice idiomatic way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? For an example if I have a list/vector how can I match a case when there is no more elements and such?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus what kind of correcting is that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [core.match](https://github.com/clojure/core.match) if desired

For example,

```
(defn foo [v] 
  (match v 
    [x] x
    [x y & more] (+ (* x y) (foo more)) 
    :else nil))
```

Comment: Is it widely used or am I searching for a pattern that is just not necessary in Clojure?

Comment: @ayanahmedov It is often used but not widely — or if you prefer it's not an idiomatism. The big difference between pattern matching and destructuring is that pattern matching is about strict structure and dispatch while destructuring is about loose structure. They don't serve the same purpose.

Comment: Frequency of use would be a poor measure of usefulness for a library that just graduated from beta in the last year.

Answer (score 0):

As A. Webb said, you can use core.match to write in pattern-matching style. However, this sort of thing can be written pretty easily with just primitive functions:

```
(defn foo [[x y & xs]]
  (cond
    (and x y) (bar y (foo xs))
    x         x
    :else     nil))
```

Comment: Your code assumes that nil and false are not legit values of the sequence.

Comment: @cgrand: That is true. It's not hard to adapt it for that case, but I thought we were talking about general forms rather than specific cases.